# Пакетная оптимизация изображений с копированием результата. На сервере

Tags: linux, apache, веб-сервер

На web-сервере имеется многоуровневая структура каталогов с jpg-изображениями. Нужно их оптимизировать, сохранив оптимизированные в новом каталоге соблюдая исходную структуру.

Например, исходная структура:

```
img/vesna/gorod/2020/
img/vesna/les/2020/
img/vesna/pole/2020/
img/leto/gorod/2020/
img/leto/les/2020/
img/leto/pole/2020/
```

Оптимизированные нужно сложить в

```
imgopt/vesna/gorod/2020/
imgopt/vesna/les/2020/
imgopt/vesna/pole/2020/
imgopt/leto/gorod/2020/
imgopt/leto/les/2020/
imgopt/leto/pole/2020/
```

Подскажете как это сделать непосредственно на сервере?
SSH доступ имеется.

PS. Насколько я нагуглил `jpegoptim` может сложить все в один каталог, а надо раскидать соответственно исходному расположению. Или же я не нашел как им это провернуть.

Comment: а Вам однократно или постоянно нужно это делать?

Comment: @KoVadim Ну как.. сейчас вот понадобилось, наверняка понадобится ещё когда-то.

Comment: можно просто сделать копию. А потом запустить где то так  `find . -name "*.jpg" -exec jpegoptim {}\;`

Comment: @KoVadim с копией - то понятно что так можно (было бы места достаточно ;)), но интересует как сделать нормально. На винде это не проблема, но объём не оптимизированных более 10гб - не накачаешься

Comment: Если я правильно понял man jpegoptim, его можно попросить выдавать результат оптимизации в stdout. Соответственно, если сделать маленькую обёрточку, которую будет запускать find, как уже написал @KoVadim, и которая будет запускать jpegoptim с перенаправлением его stdout в нужное место (sed'ом заменить в $1 img/ на imgopt/ и создать нужный путь, используя mkdir и dirname), то задача вроде как решена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pushd ./images/

find . -name \*.jpg -type f -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' src; do 
  dest=../imgopt/$(dirname "$src")
  mkdir -p "$dest"
  jpegoptim --force --dest="$dest" "$src"
done

popd
```

Перейдем в папку с картинками чтоб получать относительные пути в find.

find просто выводит список файлов с разделителем `\0` - это нужно чтоб пробелы в именах файлов не сломали список.

Дальше хитрый read, который читает этот путь в переменную по разделителю \0

dirname уберет имя файла из пути - выйдет `../imgopt/./vesna`. точка не проблема - линукс её отработает.

Создали папку и пишем jpegoptim с выхлопом в эту папку. `--force` чтоб уже оптимизированные файлы не пропустить.

Comment: Спасибо. Только один вопрос - это куда записать, как этим воспользоваться? Сорри за нубство.

Comment: В консоль прямо как есть по строчкам